# Null hypothesis testing

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means, variance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uGAB.png)

For this problem, can we simply jump to the conclusion that since the mean of X is 3, and $Y_i=0.17+0.1X_i$, the mean of $Y_i$ is just 0.3?

Comment: I've inserted the picture as a link in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expectation is a linear function, so we you can conclude that the **sample** mean of $Y$ is $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum 0.17+0.1X_i=0.17 + 0.1 \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i=0.17 + 0.1\bar{X}=0.17 + 0.1 \cdot 3=0.47$.

Comment: So it fails the test right? Since it doesn't fall into the interval $[0.2, 0.3]$. We don't need to use the standard error in this problem at all?